# How to allow missing words within phrases?

Tags: solr

lets say I want to search for the phrase

```
Max and Joe bought apples and bananas
```

I can use the proximity search `"..."~N` to allow additional words

```
Max and Joe bought a bunch of apples and bananas
```

But how to allow a few missing words as well and find

```
Max and Joe bought apples and bananas
```

---

Of cause I could query each combination

```
"and Joe bought apples and bananas"~5
"Max Joe bought apples and bananas"~5
"Max and bought apples and bananas"~5
"Max and Joe apples and bananas"~5
"Max and Joe bought and bananas"~5
...
```

But that feels terrible inefficient. What's the way to go?

**Note**: The phrase are part of a longer text. Therefore simple OR queries would not work (proximity is required)

Comment: Have you look at the minimum should match (mm) parameter? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/the-dismax-query-parser.html#mm-minimum-should-match-parameter